# Combining a list of dataframes on both axes in one line

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a list of small Dataframes with this structure:

```
                                           Group 1
question answer                                       
Q1       Population                        354.000000
         Yes                                33.333333
         No                                 33.333333
         Don't know                         33.333333
         Total                             100.000000
         Mean                                5.000000
```

with `question`and `answer` being levels of a multiindex.

Some of the dataframes have the same column name, whereas others have the same index values. The final result should contain the columns and index values from all dataframes, like this:

```
                                           Group 1      Group 2     ...
question answer                                       
Q1       Population                        354.000000  650.000000   ...
         Yes                                33.333333   66.666666   ...
         No                                 33.333333   33.333333   ...
         Don't know                         33.333333   33.333333   ...
         Total                             100.000000   100.00000   ...
         Mean                                5.000000     6.66666   ...

Q2       Population                        353.000000   648.00000   ...
         Yes                                33.333333   33.333333   ...
         No                                 33.333333   33.333333   ...
         Don't know                         33.333333   33.333333   ...
         Total                             100.000000  100.000000   ...
         Mean                                5.000000    5.000000   ...

         ...                               ...          ...         ...
```

I have made some attempts with `pd.concat()`, `df.merge()`, `df.append()` and `df.update()`, but I somehow can't do it without at least one for loop, which slows things down.

Is there a one-line solution to this that I'm somehow not seeing?

Edit:
Here's three sample dataframes (different numbers than above, but the numbers are arbitrary anyways):

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=[[random.randrange(10)] for x in range(6)], columns=['Group 1'], index=pd.MultiIndex(levels=[['Q1'], ['Population', 'Yes', 'No', "Don't know", 'Total', 'Mean']],
           codes=[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]],
           names=['question', 'answer']))

df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=[[random.randrange(10)] for x in range(6)], columns=['Group 1'], index=pd.MultiIndex(levels=[['Q2'], ['Population', 'Yes', 'No', "Don't know", 'Total', 'Mean']],
           codes=[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]],
           names=['question', 'answer']))

df3 = pd.DataFrame(data=[[random.randrange(10)] for x in range(6)], columns=['Group 2'], index=pd.MultiIndex(levels=[['Q1'], ['Population', 'Yes', 'No', "Don't know", 'Total', 'Mean']],
           codes=[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]],
           names=['question', 'answer']))
```

Comment: Can you provide code for at least two example data frames, so we can copy/paste and test?

Comment: @RubenB samples provided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) with `MultiIndex Series` created by [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and then [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html), for same ordering is added [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) with [`Index.union`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.union.html) of all indices:

```
from functools import reduce

dfs = [df1, df2, df3]
idx = reduce(lambda l,r: l.union(r, sort=False), [x.index for x in dfs])

df = pd.concat([x.stack() for x in dfs], sort=False).unstack().reindex(idx)
print (df)
                     Group 1  Group 2
question answer                      
Q1       Population      9.0      3.0
         Yes             7.0      0.0
         No              5.0      7.0
         Don't know      2.0      5.0
         Total           9.0      4.0
         Mean            5.0      0.0
Q2       Population      9.0      NaN
         Yes             6.0      NaN
         No              4.0      NaN
         Don't know      9.0      NaN
         Total           3.0      NaN
         Mean            8.0      NaN
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't preserve the order of the `answer` index level.

Comment: This works, but I am correct in assuming that this necessitates a loop when concatenating a long list of dataframes, since `Index.union()` doesn't take iterables?

Comment: @DataWiz I think you loop by df.index values, answer was edited.